# Subtracting one Array from another in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, array-difference

I've got two arrays of Tasks - created and assigned. 
I want to remove all assigned tasks from the array of created tasks.
Here's my working, but messy, code:

```
    @assigned_tasks = @user.assigned_tasks
    @created_tasks = @user.created_tasks

    #Do not show created tasks assigned to self
    @created_not_doing_tasks = Array.new
    @created_tasks.each do |task|
        unless @assigned_tasks.include?(task)
            @created_not_doing_tasks << task
        end
    end
```

I'm sure there's a better way. What is it?
Thanks :-)

Comment: I bet under the hood the answer is doing just what you've coded there.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can subtract arrays in Ruby:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] - [1,3,4]  #=> [2,5]
```

> ary - other_ary → new_ary Array Difference
>
> Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any
>   items that also appear in other_ary. The order is preserved from the
>   original array.
>
> It compares elements using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.
>
> `[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ] - [ 1, 2, 4 ]  #=>  [ 3, 3, 5 ]`
>
> If you need
>   set-like behavior, see the library class Set.

See the [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002211) documentation.

Comment: Arg. Big face-palm moment for me. For some reason I thought that wouldn't work with objects. 
Worked just fine - thanks!

Comment: careful with this, test it in IRB first, for example: [5, 5, 5, 5] - [5, 5] = [] ... the subtraction removes the unique elements in the array.

Comment: @hagope, yep, it's greedy one.

Comment: Also note, this will not work: `[1,2]-[1,2,3] => []`. But `[1,2,3]-[1,2] => [3]`. Argh.

Comment: If you think in terms of *subtraction* then this last "gotchas" actually make sense.  To *subtract* something you aren't asking for a *diff*... you are asking to subtract Y from X... if Y has something not even in X then the result is kind of 'undefined', hence the extra Y-element wouldn't be included in the X-result.

Comment: Specifically, `Array#-` is a set difference. It's more an inverse of `Array#|`, a set union, than it is of `Array#+`, concatenation (not a set operation at all!).

Comment: If you think in terms of subtraction, then if I start with 3 coins labeled 2 ([2,2,2]) and I subtract one coin labeled 2 ([2]), I would end up with 2 coins labeled 2 ([2,2]). So yes, it behaves more like a set.

Comment: to get intersection `[1,2,3,5] & [1,3,4] => [1, 3]`

Answer (score 14):

The above solution

```
a - b
```

deletes all instances of elements in array `b` from array `a`.

```
[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ] - [ 1, 2, 4 ]  #=>  [ 3, 3, 5 ]
```

In some cases, you want the result to be `[1, 2, 3, 3, 5]`.  That is, you don't want to delete all duplicates, but only the elements individually.

You could achieve this by

```
class Array
  def delete_elements_in(ary)
    ary.each do |x|
      if index = index(x)
        delete_at(index)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

test

```
irb(main):198:0> a = [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ]
=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):199:0> b = [ 1, 2, 4 ]
=> [1, 2, 4]
irb(main):200:0> a.delete_elements_in(b)
=> [1, 2, 4]
irb(main):201:0> a
=> [1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
```

The code works even when the two arrays are not sorted.  In the example, the arrays are sorted, but this is not required.

Comment: `delete_elements_in` is not available in Ruby proper (ruby 2.6.3p62)

Comment: @qaisjp, because it is defined by the writer. You shall define it, too. Look at the code above the test code.