# Replace NULL values in an array in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, null, rails-postgresql

SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3] - ARRAY[5,NULL,6]

I am using contrib _int.sql package for array operations in postgresql 8.4
In the above query there is a `NULL` in right hand side array. Because of this NULL value, it throws an error:

```
"ERROR:  array must not contain nulls"
```

Can anyone help me to remove the null values from the array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Arrays **can** contain NULL values in **PostgreSQL 8.4+**

```
db=# SELECT ARRAY[5,NULL,6];
   array
------------
 {5,NULL,6}
```

2) But you **cannot** subtract one ARRAY from another in standard PostgreSQL 8.4.

```
db=# SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3] - ARRAY[5,NULL,6];
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] - integer[]
```

3) You **can** do that in PostgreSQL 8.4 with the [contrib package intarray](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/intarray.html) installed.

4) But you **cannot** subtract arrays containing NULL values.

5) You **can** also subtract arrays in **Ruby**. See [here in the manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html), or [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192186/subtracting-one-array-from-another-in-ruby).

---

#### Solution to replace NULLs in an integer array in PostgreSQL:

Postgres **9.3** or later has **`array_replace(anyarray, NULL, anyelement)`** for *any* array. [The manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

In older versions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_int_array_replace_null (int[], int)
RETURNS int[] AS
$$
SELECT ARRAY (
    SELECT COALESCE(x, $2)
    FROM   unnest($1) x);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

[`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html) was introduced with PostgreSQL **8.4**
For older versions you can use [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_int_array_replace_null (int[], int)
RETURNS int[] AS
$$
SELECT ARRAY (
    SELECT COALESCE($1[i], $2)
    FROM   generate_series(1, array_upper($1, 1)) x(i));
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Call:

```
event=# SELECT f_int_array_replace_null (ARRAY[5,NULL,6], 0);
 f_int_array_replace_null
--------------------------
 {5,0,6}
```

**Disclaimer**: both versions are not fit for multidimensional arrays.