# How to replace a value in array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a data like below.

```
id              col1[]
---             ------
1                {1,2,3}
2                {3,4,5}
```

My question is how to use replace function in arrays.

```
select array_replace(col1, 1, 100) where id = 1;
```

but it gives an error like:

```
function array_replace(integer[], integer, integer) does not exist
```

can anyone suggest how to use it?

Comment: You're using PostgreSQL 9.2 or earlier, right?

Comment: am using postgresql 9.2

Comment: There is no `array_replace` in 9.2, that was added in 9.3. Compare the [9.2 array functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) with the [9.3 array functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).

Answer (score 5):

Your statement (augmented with the missing `FROM` clause):

```
SELECT array_replace(col1, 1, 100) FROM tbl WHERE id = 1;
```

As [commented by @mu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987139/how-to-replace-a-value-in-array#comment42507747_26987139), [`array_replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) was introduced with **pg 9.3**. I see **3 options** for older versions:

#### 1. [`intarray`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html)

As long as ...

- we are dealing with **integer arrays**.
- elements are unique.
- and the order of elements is irrelevant.

A simple and fast option would be to [install the additional module `intarray`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491184/postgresql-intarray-error-undefined-symbol-pfree/10491433#10491433), which (among other things) provides operators to subtract and add elements (or whole arrays) from/to integer arrays:

```
SELECT CASE col1 && '{1}'::int[] THEN (col1 - 1) +  100 ELSE col1 END AS col1
FROM   tbl WHERE id = 1;
```

#### 2. Emulate with SQL functions

A (slower) drop-in replacement for `array_replace()` using polymorphic types, so it works for *any* base type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_replace(anyarray, anyelement, anyelement)
  RETURNS anyarray LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT ARRAY (SELECT CASE WHEN x = $2 THEN $3 ELSE x END FROM unnest($1) x)';
```

Does not replace NULL values. Related:

- [Replace NULL values in an array in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819021/replace-null-values-in-an-array-in-postgresql/7824427#7824427)

If you need to guarantee order of elements:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

#### 3. Apply patch to source and recompile

Get the patch ["Add array_remove() and array_replace() functions"](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=84a42560c82aeb9f3690d93a0d03cf544f53b89b) from the git repo, apply it to the source of your version and recompile. May or may not apply cleanly. The older your version the worse are your chances. I have not tried that, I would rather upgrade to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own
based on this [source](http://www.depesz.com/2012/07/12/waiting-for-9-3-add-array_remove-and-array_replace-functions/) :

```
CREATE TABLE arr(id int, col1 int[]);

INSERT INTO arr VALUES (1, '{1,2,3}');
INSERT INTO arr VALUES (2, '{3,4,5}');

SELECT array(
SELECT CASE WHEN q = 1 THEN 100 ELSE q END 
FROM UNNEST(col1::int[]) q) 
FROM arr;

  array
-----------
 {100,2,3}
 {3,4,5}
```

You can create your own function and put it in your `public` schema if you still want to call by function though it will be slightly different than the original.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl SET col1 = array_replace(col1, 1, 100) WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample query for a test-array:

```
SELECT test_id,
       test_array,
       (array (
           -- Replace existing value 'int' of an array with given value 'Text'
           SELECT CASE WHEN a = '0' THEN 'MyEntry'
                       WHEN a = '1' THEN 'Apple'
                       WHEN a = '2' THEN 'Banana'
                       WHEN a = '3' THEN 'ChErRiEs'
                       WHEN a = '4' THEN 'Dragon Fruit'
                       WHEN a = '5' THEN 'Eat a Fruit in a Day'
                       ELSE 'NONE' END
           FROM UNNEST(test_array::TEXT[]) a) ::TEXT
           -- UNNEST : Lists out values of my_test_array
       ) test_result
FROM (
    --my_test_array
    SELECT 1 test_id, '{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}'::TEXT[][] test_array
) test;
```

Comment: On running this query in athena I run into the error
line 3:19: no viable alternative at input '(array ( select' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 783d65ea-d9dd-4cbf-8d9f-8f9ff6e32eab; proxy: null)
Any idea why?