# rails habtm with join model - how to find unlinked records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a habtm relationship implemented with a model that represents the join (because the join has attributes):

```
class Person
  has_many :person_photos
end

class PersonPhoto
  # has a person and a photo id, and a couple of 
  # other attributes that aren't relevant
end

class Photo
  has_many :person_photos
end
```

I'd like to add a method to the Photo class to get a list of people that are **not** in that photo. For the life of me I can't figure it out. Is it easy to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that maybe, in your photo model...

```
def people_not_tagged
    People.where("id NOT IN (?)", people_ids.empty? ? "" : people_ids)
end
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this one, but the SQL it generates is: SELECT `people`.* FROM `people` WHERE (id NOT IN 1,2) and that barfs.

Comment: Ahh -- include brackets around the ? and it works! (I edited the answer to fix it.) Thanks!

Comment: What are you building? If it's not a very small, personal app, you'll get a huuuge number of People! You might want to be more specific.

Comment: It's an in-house app so there won't be thousands of people. Actually the models aren't even People and Photo, I just used those names to make the example easier to understand.

Comment: Ok :) But with this method at least, it's easy to paginate if you need to.

Comment: Ah... it breaks if there are no people already tagged in the photo, it ends up with `(id NOT in (NULL))` :-/

Comment: Updated after testing -- the || version didn't work (still returned no  people when there were none already tagged).

Comment: Since the sql generated was `in (NULL)`, for some reason, I thought that people_ids was null... but it's an empty array, obviously ^^. But anyways, you got it now ^^.

Answer (score 0):

You could try having person has_many photos through person_photos and photo has_many people through person_photos.

Rails docs for [has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)

Then photo.find(1).people would list all the people in photo 1

Then using array subtraction people_not_in_photo = People.all - photo.find(1).people would, I think, give you what you're looking for.

Stackoverflow question on [subtracting arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192186/subtracting-one-array-from-another-in-ruby)

Comment: `people_not_in_photo = People.all - photo.find(1).people`. As is, it would really heavy, right? Maybe `people_not_in_photo = People.select(:id).map(&:id) - photo.find(1).people_ids` would be a bit better. But still, if there is a lot of users, I don't think it's a viable solution.